# Как лучше делать посимвольную обработку текстового файла

Tags: кодировка, файлы, потоки-данных, java, символы

Добры день! 
Дана задача: нужно зашифровать текст из файла (тут вопросов нет), НО как осуществить посимвольное чтение из файла, чтоб я мог манипулировать этими символами в своем массиве (присваивать символ с конкретным индексом и т.д.).

Допустим, я читаю часть текста , обрабатываю - записываю в массив, записываю содержимое массива (измененный текст) в другой файл.

И еще нужно узнать длину всего исходного текста.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, а то я запутался с различными FileInput-OutputStream, FileRider/Writer, StringBuffer/Builder.

Да, еще у меня кодировка KOI8-U (украинский яз.), пробовал выводить через:

```
public static String loadFileAsString(File file, String encoding)
            throws IOException {

        InputStreamReader f=
                (encoding==null ? new FileReader(file):new InputStreamReader( new FileInputStream(file),encoding));

        StringBuffer sb= new StringBuffer();

        try {
            char[] buf= new char[1000];
            int len;
            while ((len=f.read(buf,0,buf.length))>=0) {
                sb.append(buf,0,len);

            }
            return sb.toString();
        }catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
             System.out.println("FileNotFoundException: " + file + " exc: " + ex);
        } finally {
            try {f.close();} catch (Exception e) {};
        }
        return null;
     }
```

как говорилось в http://www.cyberforum.ru/java-j2se/thread156012.html 
получается бред, так что и шифровать не нужно)).

Так что очень нужна помощь!

Answer (score 1):

так вы можете считать содержимое файла в строку:

```
// где f - ваш input stream reader
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(f);

StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
String buff = null;
while (null != (buff = reader.readLine()))
{
    result.append(buff);
}
```

считать содержимое в массив чаров:

```
char [] characters = new char[result.length()]; 
result.getChars(0, result.length(), characters, 0);
```